# How to solve Angular subscribe error? Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'AngularFireList<unknown>'.ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from a Firebase RDB in the data service with the following function:

```
this.getOrgId()
.subscribe((orgId: string) =>
localStorage.setItem('orgId', orgId));
```

```
getOrgId() { 

  return this.db.list(/users/${this.uId}/organization/.json); 
}
```

Unfortunately I got the following error:
*Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'AngularFireList'.ts(2339)*

Does anyone has an idea how to fix it? I am completely new to JS and TS.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `this.getOrgId()` should return an *Observable*, which I doubt it does in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to fix it to return an Observable?

Comment: post . your getOrgId() method

Comment: You need to alter the `this.getOrgId()` method to return an Observable, then only can you subscribe to it. Also, this looks like a *getter* method, why exactly do you need to subscribe to it in the first place?

Comment: I tried to get the orgId like this:   getOrgId() {
    return this.db.list(`/users/${this.uId}/organization/.json`);
  }

Comment: How do i alter the method?

Answer (score 1):

To `subscribe` to `AngularFireList` you should use one of `snapshotChanges()`, `valueChanges<T>()`, `stateChanges()` or `auditTrail()`.

Change `getOrgId()` as below.

```
getOrgId() { 

  return this.db.list(/users/${this.uId}/organization/.json).valueChanges(); 
}
```